# shell if statment executing even if its not true

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a script to create/remove local user.

code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script can create or remove a local linux user.
# --------------------------------------------------------

# Ask if the user wants to create or delete user!
read -p 'Do you want to create or delete user? (c/d) : ' TO_DO
# Account creation
if [[ "${TO_DO}" -eq 'c' ]]
then
        read -p 'Enter the username to create : ' USER_NAME
        read -p 'Enter name of account holder : ' REAL_NAME
        read -ps 'Enter the password to set : ' PASSWORD_P1
        read -ps 'Please retype password : ' PASSWORD_P2
        if [[ "${PASSWORD_P1}" -eq "${PASSWORD_P2}" ]]; then
                # Creating user.
                useradd -c "${REAL_NAME}" -m "${USER_NAME}"
                # Setting password.
                echo "${PASSWORD_P1}\n${PASSWORD_P1}" | passwd "${USER_NAME}"
                # Force user to reset password on next login
                passwd -e "${USER_NAME}"
                echo 'Account created succesfully'
        else
                echo 'The password do not match.'
                exit 2
        fi
elif [[ "${TO_DO}" -eq 'd' ]]; then
        read -p 'Enter the username to delete : ' USER_NAME
        userdel -r "${USER_NAME}"
        echo 'Account deleted successfully'
else
        echo 'Please choose appropriate options!'
        exit 3
fi
```

WHEN I CHOOSE THE "d" OPTION. THE STATEMENTS OF "c" OPTIONS ARE EXECUTED.

Shell:

```
sudo ./localUserManager.sh
Do you want to create or delete user? (c/d) : d
Enter the username to create : ^C
```

(HERE THE OPTION TO DELETE USERNAME SHOULD COME!)

Comment: `-eq` is an arithmetic operator, use `=` or `==` for string comparisons.

Comment: isn't "=" assignment operator?

Comment: No. As argument inside `[[ ... ]]`, it is the equality comparison operator. You *can't* perform assignment inside double brackets, so there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Use `=`, not `-eq`, for string comparision.

---

It is true. `-eq` is for *integer* comparison, and in this context, a string is treated as a parameter name to expand. If the parameter is undefined, it defaults to 0. As such, let's say the user enters `d`. Then

```
if [[ "${TO_DO}" -eq 'c' ]]
```

becomes after paramter expansion

```
if [[ "d" -eq 'c' ]]
```

As neither `d` nor `c` is a defined variable, `-eq` expands each to 0, with the resulting comparison being

```
if [[ 0 -eq 0 ]];
```

which is of course true.

(To see this expansion in practice, try the following

```
c=0      # explicitly set c to 0
unset d  # explicitly unset d, so that it isn't defined
if [[ c -eq d ]]; then
  # c is defined, so $c -> 0 is used
  # d is not defined, so a default of 0 is used
  echo "equal"
else
  echo "not equal"
fi
```

Now try the same thing with `c` set to a non-zero value, or
with both `c` and `d` set to the same value.
)

If you use `=`, then string comparision occurs as expected.

```
if [[ "${TO_DO}" = 'c' ]];
```

becomes

```
if [[ "d" = 'c' ]];
```

which is false.

Comment: what do you mean by:: "As neither d nor c is defined, it further becomes". they arent variables...

Comment: But they are *treated* as parameter names when used as arguments for `-eq`.

Comment: Try `c=3; d=3; [[ c -eq d ]] && echo equal`.

Comment: ok got it .....